# Trouble returning MSSQL query results from PHP function

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm getting a strange error when attempting to return the results of a working sqlsrv_query function call.

I have set up:

```
function test($someinput, &$someoutput)
{
  //set up $dbc and $dbcOptions
  //generate tsql
  $params = array();
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $tsql, $params, $dbcOptions);
  $someoutput = $stmt;
  return $stmt;
}

$outputvar;
$results = test($inputvar, $outputvar);

//---ERROR being thrown here
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
//$rows2 = sqlsrv_num_rows($outputvar);
//---ERROR being thrown here
```

In both lines (doesn't matter which I use), I'm getting an error in my `php-errors.log` file saying

```
PHP Warning:  sqlsrv_num_rows(): 2 is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resource in
E:\inetpub\wwwroot\directory\searchtest.php on line 58
```

which `searchtest.php` is the file I'm working on and line 58 is where I have the error-producing code.

Why can I not pass query results from a function like this?

Comment: `return $stmt;` missing the variable symbol

Comment: @Mihai Thanks, I corrected that, but the code still behaves the same.

Comment: Could be a scope issue. Try passing `$dbc` to your function, or (*not recommended*) to make it `global $dbc;` in your function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That seems to have fixed it. Write this as an answer and I'll vote it up and mark it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Will do and you're welcome Joel.

Comment: It has been done Joel, *cheers*. Glad it got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's wish to mark as answered, comment (*slightly modified*) to answer:

This sounds be a [**scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue.

Try passing `$dbc` to your function (*best*), or (*not recommended*) to make it `global $dbc;` in your function.

Comment: I was able to use what you deemed the best method of passing in the `$dbc`.

Comment: @JoelTrauger That's great Joel, it is better. `global` is thought of as being "evil", *so they say*. It has its pros & cons.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, that you have an error in your SQL statment.
You can call `sqlsrv_errors` after:

`$stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $tsql, $params, $dbcOptions);`

```
if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should find the error.